# Solve Lagrangian function for utility

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, utility

I have the following Utility function: 
\begin{align}
U = w^\prime\mu  
\end{align}

and Langrangian function subject to constraint:
\begin{align}
F (w, \lambda)= w^\prime\mu - \lambda(w^\prime i - 1)
\end{align}

I would like to have an expression for w so that I can calculate the weights. Does anyone know how to solve the system and obtain the function for 'w'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the utility function be like this?

$$ L(w, \lambda) = w' \mu - \lambda\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i -1 \right)  $$

In that case, let: $w'\mu $ be $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \mu_i$, with the constraint that the weights must sum $1$.

$$ L(w, \lambda) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \mu_i -\lambda\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i -1 \right)  $$

Then you just have to find each derivative for the problem, meaning:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i} = 0 \ , \forall i $$

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0  $$

If you had more constraints, you'd have to find also the derivative for the rest of constraints, meaning a vector $\lambda' $

Comment: Yes, I think so! thanks. Do you know how to solve it, because I am still stuck..

Comment: But I still cannot figure out what the expressions for 'w' is.. I am trying to find the derivatives and set them equal to each other, but cannot find an expression for 'w'

Comment: There was a typo in my text. Look the derivatives, it will help now, I hope. But do you have a numerical example to which you want a solution?